# Cannot use timestamps on index/update requests in ES 6.x and above. Please remove the [es.mapping.timestamp] setting

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark Structured Streaming to write to an Elasticsearch 6.2.0 Sink:

```scala
dataDf  
  .writeStream
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append)
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .queryName("ElasticSink")
  .option("checkpointLocation", s"${s3Url}/checkpoint_elasticsearch")
  ...
  .option("es.mapping.id", "TransactionID")
  .option("es.mapping.timestamp", "InvoiceDateString")
  .start("pos-transactions/broadcast") //ES index
```

However, Elasticsearch is complaining:

> Cannot use timestamps on index/update requests in ES 6.x and above. Please remove the [es.mapping.timestamp] setting

Is there an alternative option that I can use to declare the timestamp field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I created a mapping document and this worked for me perfectly:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html